# IntelliJ IDEA debug can not preview values on every line

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA version is 2018.2.5 (Ultimate Edition) build #IU-182.4892.20 for Mac.

I have a trouble when I debug.

It should preview some info on most line when I debug normally, like this:

[image: normally preview]

But, my debug info disappear like this:

[image: abnormally preview]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the [Show values inline](https://i.imgur.com/bgqXzH8.png) option enabled?

Comment: @CrazyCoder oh! Thank you very much, it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the **Show values inline** debugger option:

[image: Show values inline]